# Custom Rest Service with OAuth 2.0 and Connected Apps

Tags: rest

Is there any example/sample code of Custom Rest web service in Apex with  OAuth 2.0 and Connected Apps? Also wanted to know how to expose the object based on the selective parameters. If parameters are not provided it will return all the data of the object in JSON otherwise queried & return the data based on the parameters.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link https://github.com/jesperfj/sfdc-oauth-playground. Hope this can help you.